# Convert a joomla website to the mobile website?

Tags: android, joomla, mobile-website

Im trying to create a mobile website for an existing joomla website. I'm an android developer and a new bee in wweb development. can you please guide me on how can i move, what steps i need to follow, which is the best way.. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually in the process of doing this right now. I've decided to use the [Mobile Joomla](http://www.mobilejoomla.com/) component. It makes it relatively easy to get going, but I had to tweak some things along the way. One thing I did was rip out [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) and replaced it with [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Although now they may have a downloadable jQuery Mobile theme.

I also had a couple problems with the URL structure being a little bit different on the mobile site and not including some important URL parameters, but hell, it's Joomla. Anyone who's ever worked with Joomla knows that's almost expected. Ended up fixing it with pure tinkering.

One nice thing about using mobile Joomla is it separates templates for several different types of phones. There is an iPhone template, XHTML template, etc. If you use something like jQuery Mobile, it'll work on nearly any iPhone, Android or Blackberry. I added jQuery Mobile to both the XHTML template and iPhone template because I was aiming for strong iPhone compatibility, but I probably could have just used the XHTML template alone and used it for all devices.

In the process of developing this mobile site, I've also developed a mobile slider which utilizes iPhone swipe gestures. I plan on releasing the slider module to the public once the site itself launches. I tested it on Android and it seems to work nicely as well.

Hope that helps at least a bit.

Comment: hey which one will you prefer create a new website using jquery or convert the existing joomal website

Comment: I would personally use a component for Joomla websites to run better on mobiles or some use a template that is mobile compatiable. Rocketheme and Yootheme provide templates that run extremely well on mobiles ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you done want to use any components you can always develop mobile template for joomla: [Joomla! mobile development](http://joomla.styletricks.net/index.php/joomla-mobile-development)
 or use one of new generation responsive layout.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need something proper and you don't want fiddle long, you can also use our tool, [xapp-studio.com](http://xapp-studio.com). Mobile web apps are free.

Otherwise, there isn't much more to say than sobering did.